# EE1 - Include entry category ID in an embed

Tags: categories, ee1, embeds

I usually use Low Variables or Stash for this, but thought I would toss this one out there anyway to see if I have just been over complicating my templates.

I have a template that pulls in an entry. The entry will have a category assigned to it. This entry also has another section using the same category group. I need to embed a template that displays a list of all the titles in that section with that category. My problem is trying to nest that category id in the embed without using a plug-in.

So in my template, I have something like:

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="whatever" limit="1" status="not closed"}

{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

I need to embed a template inside that. I have tried the following:

```
{embed="total/product_list" cat="{category_id}"}
```

and

```
{embed="total/product_list" cat="{categories}{category_id}{/categories}"}
```

and

```
{categories}
    {embed="total/product_list" cat="{category_id}"}
{/categories}
```

I know parsing order has me in a conundrum. like I said, I just thought I would see what solutions were out there. I'm always open to an education.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `{embed="total/product_list" cat="{categories}{category_id}{/categories}"}`

That's the one. Embeds run dead last in parse order, so there should be no issue there. Just make sure that you then use `category="{embed:cat}"` in your embedded template.

Comment: HaHa!! Derek, it was an ID10T error...  I had dynamic="no" instead of dynamic="off" WOW!!! You would think that as many of these EE1 sites I still get drug into that I would remember that.   Thanks man!